# Null values with PIVOT in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need your help for this query

The table has the structure

```
CREATE TABLE produccion
(
    FECHAEMISION  VARCHAR(8),
    ALMACEN VARCHAR(10), 
    ARTICULO VARCHAR(30), 
    CANTIDAD  INT, 
    DIA INT,
    NOMBREDIA VARCHAR(10)
);
```

And the data is

```
INSERT INTO dbo.produccion (FECHAEMISION, ALMACEN, ARTICULO, CANTIDAD, DIA, NOMBREDIA)
VALUES ('15/03/21', 'HILO', '10/1 PPACOE 65/35', 1449.5, 15, 'Lunes'),
       ('16/03/21', 'HILO', '10/1 PPACOE 65/35', 1451.3, 16, 'Martes'),
       ('15/03/21', 'HILO', '18/1 PPACOE 65/35', 2716.8, 15, 'Lunes'),
       ('16/03/21', 'HILO', '18/1 PPACOE 65/35', 4072.2, 16, 'Martes'),
       ('17/03/21', 'HILO', '18/1 PPACOE 65/35', 3044.4, 17, 'Miércoles'),
       ('15/03/21', 'PTERMINADO', 'ATENAS-220 80/20-M', 553, 15, 'Lunes'),
       ('16/03/21', 'PTERMINADO', 'ATENAS-220 80/20-M', 2177, 16, 'Martes'),
       ('17/03/21', 'PTERMINADO', 'ATENAS-220 80/20-M', 1748, 17, 'Miércoles'),
       ('18/03/21', 'PTERMINADO', 'ATENAS-220 80/20-M', 556, 18, 'Jueves'),
       ('16/03/21', 'PTERMINADO', 'I5-292/29', 700, 16, 'Martes'),
       ('17/03/21', 'PTERMINADO', 'I5-292/29', 1456, 17, ' Miércoles'),
       ('18/03/21', 'PTERMINADO', 'I5-292/29', 856, 18, 'Jueves'),
       ('15/03/21', 'PTERMINADO', 'UIH-270', 2438, 15, 'Lunes'),
       ('16/03/21', 'PTERMINADO', 'UIH-270', 2798, 16, 'Martes'),
       ('17/03/21', 'PTERMINADO', 'UIH-270', 2769, 17, 'Miércoles'),
       ('18/03/21', 'PTERMINADO', 'UIH-270', 2660, 18, 'Jueves'),
       ('19/03/21', 'PTERMINADO', 'UIH-270', 3483, 19, 'Viernes'),
       ('20/03/21', 'PTERMINADO', 'UIH-270', 2891, 20, 'Sábado'),
       ('21/03/21', 'PTERMINADO', 'UIH-270', 3042, 21, 'Domingo'),
```

The query result is:

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DnULH.png)

And the expected result is something like

[expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eZFaJ.png)

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: As per the question guide, please DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text. And we need to see the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to "FEED" your pivot with only the required columns.

**Example**

```
Select *
 From  (
        Select ARTICULO
              ,CANTIDAD
              ,NOMBREDIA
        from produccion
       ) src
 Pivot (sum(CANTIDAD) for NOMBREDIA in ([Domingo],[Lunes],[Martes],[Miércoles],[Jueves],[Sábado],[Viernes])) pvt
```

**EDIT - IF BY CHANCE YOU NEED DYNAMIC**

```
Declare @SQL nvarchar(max) = N'
Select *
From (
        Select ARTICULO
              ,CANTIDAD
              ,NOMBREDIA
        from produccion
     ) A
 Pivot (sum(CANTIDAD) For [NOMBREDIA] in (' + Stuff((Select Distinct ',' + QuoteName(NOMBREDIA) From  produccion Order By 1 For XML Path('')),1,1,'')  + ') ) p
'
Exec(@SQL);
```

Comment: Thank you @John Cappelletti you saved my day

Comment: @SQLrookie Always happy to help